# Como criar um endpoint que faz um download de um arquivo local assim que requisitado no Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, api, download

Tenho um arquivo no meu projeto no qual preciso disponibilizar para download, através de um endpoint que ao ser requisitado fará o download automaticamente, porém não posso usar nenhum framework, somente Nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você não está utilizando o Express, para fazer o download de um arquivo local você pode fazer assim:

```
const http = require("http");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const fs = require('fs');

http
  .createServer((req, response) => {

    // Rotas
    const url = req.url;
    if (url === "/download") {
        const filePath = "/caminho/do/arquivo.zip";
        const fileName = "nome_do_arquivo.zip";

        // Verificar se o arquivo existe no caminho informado
        fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                response.writeHead(400, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
                response.end("ERROR File does not exist");
            } else {
                response.writeHead(200, {
                    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                    "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + fileName
                });
                fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response);
                
            }
            
        });
    }
    
  })
  .listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}...`);
  });
```

No exemplo acima, foi utilizando o filesystem para verificar se o arquivo existe, em caso positivo, o header da resposta é alterado (content-type e content-disposition). A extensão do arquivo de exemplo foi zip, mas poderia ser qualquer outra extensão.

```
const fs = require('fs');

(....)

fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        //Arquivo nao localizado
    } else {
        //Arquivo localizado, alterar o header da requisição e fazer download.
    }
    
});
```

Se você estiver usado o Express, seria mais fácil, ficaria assim:

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  const file = `${__dirname}/caminho/do/arquivo.zip`;
  res.download(file); 
});
```